# If else conditions to create a new column in dataframe in python

Tags: python

I have a data frame like this.

```
    FOOD_ID  Cumulative_addition
0       110     0       
1       110     15      
2       110     15      
3       110     35      
4       111     0       
5       111     10
6       111     10
```

I want to add another column that gives the addition only for a particular FOOD ID. The final data frame that I want looks like below....

```
    FOOD_ID  Cumulative_addition  Addition_Only
0       110     0                     0
1       110     15                   15
2       110     15                    0
3       110     35                   20
4       111     0                     0
5       111     10                   10
6       111     10                    0
```

I know how to do this in excel using if statement but do not know how to do it in python.

Comment: I strongly recommend reading the Pandas docs, this is really the basics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try :

```py
df['Addition_only'] = (df.groupby('FOOD_ID').Cumulative_addition.shift(-1) - df.Cumulative_addition).shift(1).fillna(0)
```

**Detail**

```
df.groupby('FOOD_ID').Cumulative_addition.shift(-1)
```

Will give group the cumulative addition column grouped by food id and then shift it by 1 row.

The you can subtract the original column to get the diff and shift it back by one row.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. but say if I want to fill the na values by the first element of the FOOD_ID group. I mean to say that if for ID 111, the first row for Cumulative has 10 and for that the first row of addition only should be 10 and not 0. then how to do that?